# In NHibernate, can I have a criteria query return a list of one property instead of a list of objects?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm a bit green with the criteria api. So far, I've been able to get a list of nhibernate objects by using  .List().ToList() on an ICriteria object.

I was just wondering if it was possible, say, to get a list of ints of all the ID #s of the objects that would have been returned, instead of returning the objects.

I know you can do this with HQL but I'm searching the database with dynamic lists from the user gui so the criteria api seems to be the better option.

Thanks.

Isaac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Projections to return only a subset of the properties of an object.